# Accurate general description of Regression versus Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, infinite

So I have the following problem: I realized (while writing my master thesis) that I am still not sure/have vague descriptions of some of the machine learning principles.

For instance, I vaguely remember that at some point I heard the following description:

> The output (label) of a classification task is *discrete* and *finite* while the output (label) of a regression task is *continuous* and can be *infinite*

The one word that I am unsure of is *infinite* for regression in this description.

For instance, if you assume that (for whatever reason) you have 2D data points that are almost distributed like a sine wave (with some noise) and you use polyfit to fit a polynomial of k-degree on it (see Figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5xSO.jpg) here k = 8). Now you have some data in a specific range, e.g., here the range of available points in the x-direction is [0,12], which is used to fit the polynomial.

However wouldn't you be able to quickly get the y-result for the value x = 1M (or an arbitrarily large number), as you have the general shape of the polynomial? Is that not what infinite labels mean?

Maybe I am just wrongly remembering stuff that I learned years ago ;).

best regards

Comment: How many numbers are there between 1 and 2 considering a continuous space? There's your answer. 
I know it is not infinite due to hardware constraints on float representation and bit underflow, but that's the difference. The classificator will fit the answer to one of the possibilities given in the target axis, while the regressor will fit a value in the continuous range of (min(target), max(target))

Comment: I am not sure about this. If one thinks about neural networks for example, if your output neuron has a linear activation function in principle also outputs outside of max(target) are possible, right?

Comment: Yes. I meant that if you limited any +infinity = max(target) and -infinity = min(target) in case you have a closed boundary of a continuous space. If its an answer that can be in the real numbers your range would be (-inf, +inf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a question more fitting for the more theoretically inclined sites of StackExchange, like [Stats Stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com) [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com), or the [Data Science Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), which [conveniently also provide answers to your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification). 
But not quite. In any case, your problem seems to be on the distinction between *input* and *output*. The type of task (i.e. either classificaiton or regression) is solely based on the **output** of your model, but has nothing to do with the **input**.

You could have a ton of "continuous input variables" (or even a mixture with distinct ones), and still call it a classification task, if it has a distinct amount of output values.

Furthermore, the *infinite* simply refers to the fact that these values are not bounded, i.e. you cannot restrict your regression task to a specific range easily. If you suddenly input a value completely outside of your training value range (as with your example), you will likely get an "infinite" `y` value, since your network will only be trained on this specific range; a problem that also happens with polynomial fitting, as the following example shows:
[image]

The red line could be the learned function for your network, so if you suddenly go far beyond known values, you likely get some extreme value (unless you train very well). 
Opposed to that, the classification network would still predict any of the given classes. I like to imagine it kind of a [Voronoi diagram](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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): Even if your point is arbitrarily far from any of the previous points, it will still belong to some category.

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of these StackExchange sites.
And thank you for your answer.
Okay so I would not expect to get good estimates in the extrapolated range (i.e. range outside of the training range). However it is possible? You write it is not bounded, so can you than write that they are infinite?

best regards

Comment: You're welcome. I'm merely pointing this out for future reference; as you can see, the answer should still contain all the relevant information :)

Comment: What do you mean "is it possible"? If you are referring to making predictions outside of your training range: Yes, of course. Your network does not care about input values, and will always compute something. If you are talking about getting *good* results in extrapolated regions: Depends on whether your network is overfitting or not, but generally very hard. Also infinity is generally a very strong word, and you don't really know much about the function that the network describes, but I would argue that, *yes*, you can say it is infinite.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I wanted to hear. I think this can be closed then. One last word to this: I think that this was a description from an introduction course at university, so I guess while it is not wrong, it is somewhat ambiguous in the meaning and a very broad description and is more suitable for beginners. 

Thank you, have a nice day